# How to use highcharts' charts.get(location) in React?

Tags: react-native, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm using highcharts in React , and I want to invoke .get() method. the official demo is like :

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
    locationA = chart.get('locationA'),
    locationB = chart.get('locationB'),
    locationC = chart.get('locationC'),
    locationD = chart.get('locationD');
```

and I want to get chat in React , so I also use highcharts-react lib , I create a ref like this :

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.chartComponent = React.createRef();
    }

render() {
        console.dir(usaBubbleData);
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <HighchartsReact
                    highcharts={Highcharts}
                    constructorType={"mapChart"}
                    options={maplineOptions}
                    ref={this.chartComponent}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }

componentDidMount() {
        var locationA = this.chartComponent.get("locationA"),
}
```

and I got an error :
`× TypeError: this.chartComponent.get is not a function`

I don't know are the same instance with the ref in React and `var chart = $('.container').highcharts()`?

can any one tell me what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update : I have fix this by myself.

infact the chart instance is not this.chartComponent , it's `this.chartComponent.current.char`